# Remove the last char for the last item of a django template loop

Tags: python, django, django-templates

I have this django template:

```
<script type="application/ld+json">
    {
      "@context": "https://schema.org",
      "@type": "FAQPage",
      "mainEntity": [
      {% for q_a_ins in q_a_set %}
        {
            "@type": "Question",
            "name": "{{ q_a_ins.question }}",
            "acceptedAnswer": {
              "@type": "Answer",
              "text": "{{ q_a_ins.answer }}"
            }
        },
        {% endfor %}
          ]
    }
    </script>
```

The result is:

```
<script type="application/ld+json">
    {
      "@context": "https://schema.org",
      "@type": "FAQPage",
      "mainEntity": [
          
    {
        "@type": "Question",
        "name": "q1",
        "acceptedAnswer": {
          "@type": "Answer",
          "text": "a1"
        }
      },
          
    {
        "@type": "Question",
        "name": "q2",
        "acceptedAnswer": {
          "@type": "Answer",
          "text": "a2"
        }
      },

          ]
    }
    </script>
```

The result is exactly what I want except one tiny little character!!

The last comma in the list causing me trouble and I am getthing error in structured data testing tool. How can I remove comma from the last

```
    },

          ]
```

?

The result I need is this :

```
<script type="application/ld+json">
    {
      "@context": "https://schema.org",
      "@type": "FAQPage",
      "mainEntity": [
          
    {
        "@type": "Question",
        "name": "q1",
        "acceptedAnswer": {
          "@type": "Answer",
          "text": "a1"
        }
      },
          
    {
        "@type": "Question",
        "name": "q2",
        "acceptedAnswer": {
          "@type": "Answer",
          "text": "a2"
        }
      }

          ]
    }
    </script>
```

How can I remove that comma?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can compare the `forloop.counter` and the length of the set, and only add the comma if they are not equal.

```
<script type="application/ld+json">
{
  "@context": "https://schema.org",
  "@type": "FAQPage",
  "mainEntity": [
  {% for q_a_ins in q_a_set %}
    {
        "@type": "Question",
        "name": "{{ q_a_ins.question }}",
        "acceptedAnswer": {
          "@type": "Answer",
          "text": "{{ q_a_ins.answer }}"
        }
    }{% if q_a_set|length != forloop.counter %},{% endif %}
    {% endfor %}
      ]
}
</script>
```